# Copy All Day event with MS Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, flow

I have a SP online site using an events calendar and a flow which is trying to copy an event from a different calendar to my current calendar.

The flow works fine for events with limited time. For example a meeting from 2:00 to 3:00 pm gets copied just fine.

When I try and copy All Day events the start time gets moved to the prior day. The end time is just fine and ends at the same time, but the start time is always one day earlier/

I found some threads that suggest it has to do with converting time zones, so I used [convertFromUtc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#convertfromutc) with a compose action. It is strange that for regular events I don't need to modify the times and I don't have to modify the end times, but whatever I'll give it a try.

BTW the starting time for a calendar event is called *EventDate* internally. I also found [this resource for MS time zone values](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/973627/microsoft-time-zone-index-values) and [this resource for

The time comes from the original trigger like **2020-01-29T00:00:00Z** Meaning midnight on January 29 in UTC. If I do `convertFromUtc('EventDate','Pacific Standard Time','O')` it changes it to **2020-01-28T16:00:00Z** which still sets it to a day earlier. If I manually change it to **2020-01-29T16:00:00Z** (date+1) it does work. I also found the `convertTimeZone()` function, it is the same, just with more arguments.

Is there a way to properly convert the EventDate (start date-time) for an all day event using MS Flow?

However if I use the `convertFromUtc()` function my regular event start times get messed up. Do I just need to make a condition that if it is an all day event it will need to be adjusted and if not then don't? Is there an easier way?

**Edit**

A little more info. I thought perhaps my regular time-bound events were working because they didn't start at midnight. But that wasn't the case. A regular event starting at 12:00 am and going for one hour worked just fine.

The problem seems to be confined to the start time for all day events and some conversion that happens when creating an all day event that doesn't happen when it isn't.

I've added a screenshot of my solution -- add 24 hours to the start time if it is an all day event. Not sure if that helps.

[image]

Comment: Is the flow running on a schedule? Can you share a screenshot of the flow with the action expanded? Feel free to blot out personal information.

Comment: Using a created or modified trigger. I'll add a screenshot.

Comment: Check the regional settings of the SharePoint site in site settings.

Comment: Both sites are set to Pacific time. Not sure what I'm checking for or how it would only affect the start time of all day events, but not other kinds of events.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you find an answer to this?